# Windows 8 on Lenovo Ideapad z500

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, lenovo-laptop

I recently bought a new Lenovo Ideapad Z500 with only DOS on it.
Then during the Windows 8 installation I accidentally deleted the partitions and now I have 3 partitions, 1 of them has the Type "OEM(reserved)".

I can not proceed installing Windows because whenever I choose a partition, the installer tells me that it has to GPT for me to install Windows.
It seems to me that the only option I have is either deleting the OEM partition or formatting it, because I can't do anything with the other 2 partitions.

The question is, is deleting/formatting the OEM partition the right way to fix this or is there a solution I can't seem to find?

Comment: I have the ideapad S205 and got rid of the OEM partition as it serves no real purpose. Just get rid of all partitions and partition the drive properly. Then the Windows 8 installer should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem, I for some reason was scared of deleting the OEM partition but you were absolutely right!

Comment: Glad it helped. Lenovo ships their machines with Windows, but there's also a cheaper line up that ships with Freedos. I assume that they partition all drives with the OEM partition before it's even determined if the drive ends up in a Laptop that has Windows on it where it actually serves a purpose, or Freedos where it's most likely useless. I'm just guessing though since it's quite a while I kicked mine off the HDD. Can't really remember what was on it, if anything.

Comment: I'm going to guess that partition probably had some rescue information on it . . .